# Sharing port 80 for NetTcpBinding and BasicHttpBinding in IIS 8 hosted WCF service possible?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-8

I have created a .NET 4.0 WCF service to transfer large files from and to clients. Several sources in the web suggest that streaming via `netTcpBinding` performs significantly better than streaming via `basicHttpBinding` (streaming, mtom enabled).

On the other hand, establishing a connection to the server via `net.tcp` is reported to be prone to fail, in most cases due to firewalls, proxies or other company networking restrictions, while establishing a http connection on port 80 can be taken for granted.

What I'd like to do is to provide the streaming service with both http and net.tcp endpoints on the server side. The client tries to connect to the net.tcp endpoint, and in case of a connection error, connect to the http endpoint.

Is there a way to share port 80 between my http and net.tcp endpoints? I'm using IIS 8 as service host, the clients are tied to .NET 4.0, denying the use of .NET 4.5's newly introduced `NetHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

You can share ports between multiple basicHttp bindings, or between multiple netTcp bindings, but unfortunately you can't mix and have both netTcp and basicHttp share a port. WCF will give you an `AddressAlreadyInUseException` for that.